# MultiShardQuery on SQL Azure Elastic Scale with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

I am new in Azure and I am trying to implement multishard query using Elastic Scale and Entity Framework. Unfortunately I am not able to find any example solutions or good practises to achieve that target. Can anyone help me in this issue? I would be very grateful for some materials to study or hints. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your question on multi-shard queries with Elastic Scale and EF. Currently, a straight-forward integration like the one you probably saw for data-dependent routing is not available for multi-shard queries. This is an area we are currently investing in, though. Please contact me directly over email at torsteng(at)microsoft(dot)com and we can discuss whether your use case is a good fit and we can get you unblocked.

Thanks,
Torsten

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2015, Having come across similar requirements, I contacted Torsten to see if the situation has changed, kindly he got back to me.

> Hi Matt,
>
> If your cross-db querying scenario with EF is limited to read-only access on >the shards, I’d suggest to take a look at Elastic Query for SQL DB – currently >in preview. The best entry points are probably the following documents:
>
> - Overview: https://azure.microsoft.com/enus/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-overview/
> - Step-by-step tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started/
>
> With Elastic Query set up, you can point an EF DbContext to the external tables >you have defined using the Elastic Query DDL. That DbContext can then be used >for everything that requires cross-db querying. This is a somewhat intricate >mix between code-first and db-first. But, it should get you off the ground.

The instructions seem simple enough, but do involve setting up another database (at the moment premium) in azure.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to the thread since now the sample for using elastic database tools (previously known as Elastic Scale) is now available with EF [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-use-entity-framework-applications-visual-studio/).

Hope this helps! 
Thanks
Silvia Doomra